# What is the conditional probability density $f_{X|Y_1}(x|y_1)$ if $y=G(x)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function, change-of-variable

Let's say we have random variables $X$ and $Y$, $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with densities $f_X(x)$, $f_Y(y)$, and we also have $y = G(x)$ (where $G$ is a bijective, differentiable function). I know that $f_{X}(x) = f_Y(y) |\det{(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x})}|$, but what can be said about $f_{X|Y_1}(x|y_1)$?

It seems like the density should be zero where $G(x)_1 \neq y_1$ and infinite where $G(x)_1 = y_1$, so more specifically, can we find $\lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0} f_{X|Y_1}(x|z-\frac{\epsilon}{2} <y_1<z+\frac{\epsilon}{2}) \times \epsilon$? ($f_{X|Y_1}(x|...)$  is the conditional probability density of $x$ given $y_1$ is in the range $(z-\frac{\epsilon}{2}, z+\frac{\epsilon}{2}))$

Comment: The conditional distribution of $X$ conditionally on $Y$ has no PDF since the support of $(X,Y)$ is (a subset of) the set $\{(x,y)\mid y=G(x)\}$, which, as soon as $G$ is continuous, has Lebesgue measure zero. IOW, $f_{X\mid Y}$ does not exist.

Comment: Yes, but can we find something like $lim_{\epsilon \to 0} p(x|z-\frac{\epsilon}{2}<y_1<z+\frac{\epsilon}{2}) \times \epsilon$ ?

Comment: Every such limit would be $0$ since the conditional probability in it is at most $1$, and you multiply it by $\epsilon$, which goes to $0$.

Comment: Why would the conditional probability in it be at most 1 if we're dealing with densities of continuous variables? (I meant to use $p(x|...)$ as a density). I would think that it goes to infinity as $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: Conditional probabilities are always in $(0,1)$. If you have a specific idea based on conditional probability **densities**, you should expand on it in your question.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying; I've updated the question. Is it clear what I'm asking now?

Comment: What is $f_{X|Y_1}(x|z-\frac{\epsilon}{2} <y_1<z+\frac{\epsilon}{2})$ in the revised version? You do not define it.

Comment: What I'm trying to get at is the conditional distribution of $x$, given that $y_1$ is in the range $(z - \frac{\epsilon}{2}, z + \frac{\epsilon}{2})$. Is there a clearer way of writing this?